# Explain this Modular Arithmetic Expression in Z[i]

Tags: modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\pi = a+bi$ and $\lambda = c+ di$ be relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. They also said that they were "primary" meaning that $\pi = \lambda = 1 (\text{mod } (1+i)^3)$, though I suspect this is not needed for the statement to be true.

Anyways, the statement is:
$c\pi \equiv ac + bd ~(\text{mod } \lambda)$

How does is this true? I can't see it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well $\pi = a+bi$ ie $c\pi = ac + bci$. Recognise the $ac$ bit that you find in the final equation?

Now try adding and substracting $bd$ which is the term missing and you get $c\pi = ac + bd - bd + bci$.

So you have the $ac+bd$ bit you're interested in, all you need to do is finish it by expressing the other two terms as a multiple of $\lambda = c+di$ and the job is done.